# HTML5 canvas graph for notch filter using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, graph, html5-canvas, web-audio-api

I want to draw a graph for audio notch filter by using an HTML5 `<canvas>`. To do this I have tried with [WebAudio API](http://webaudioapi.com/samples/frequency-response/). But it is not working with Internet Explorer. I was trying to draw a graph like below in the image shown. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Within this graph, I need to draw a grid, and I need to draw a graph on top of that grid.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer does not support the Web Audio API.  They are committed to implementing Web Audio in their new web browser, Microsoft Edge (formerly Project Spartan), but it has not yet been released.

Comment: Thanks for your answer is there any javascript logic to get the graph like audio notch filter.

Comment: There's no "make a filter that follows this hand-drawn curve", no.  You could make a UI that enabled multiple notch filters, and use the getFrequencyResponse() method on BiquadFilterNode to figure out what the curve should look like.